# Asynchronous processing of file upload in Django

Tags: django, upload

When you upload file with Django, the response won't be returned until the file upload has completed. If the uploaded file is large, it will take a long time, during which the user can't do anything but wait. Is there any way to implement asynchronous processing of file uploading? So, when a file is uploading backend, the user can do some other operation on the current page without interrupting the upload?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You need task management. Celery is what you at after.

Comment: Technically I dont think celery is specifically needed if the OP just does an ajax POST. Though if they want it more interactive then they would have to use either a flash uploader, or celery async task and just keep polling the status for it to register complete

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to process the file uploading with multithread, but the thread for stream reading is always exiting with sigment fault. I'll try to use celery asyc task.

Comment: That is pretty far from a valuable answer. Celery task cannot accept a file-like object as its argument, because it needs its arguments to be JSON-serializable. Also, there is the maximum argument size for brokers (at least for RabbitMQ).

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that it has been more that 5 years since this question was asked but I have similar problem and there are no "simple answers" on SO.

For your problem I may suggest using a [progress bar](https://github.com/ouhouhsami/django-progressbarupload) (if using Django forms). Uploading a file asynchronously [might not be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16218111/3623609) in Django.

In my case the browser element is not crucial and I am considering moving the file upload from browser upload to some sort of FTP / AWS S3 file storage and working on this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like https://github.com/jeanphix/django-resumable is designed for that (never tried it though). There is also a version for admin site - https://github.com/jonatron/django-admin-resumable-js

UPD: django-resumable is now abandoned, so I ended up creating my own fork with support for S3 and Inline Admin Views. You can try it here, feedback very much is welcome – https://github.com/DataGreed/django-admin-async-upload