# Celery task for file uploading in django wizard

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a WizardView covering two forms, the second one has a FileField. Is it possible to create a Celery task for uploading a file from that FileField?

Should I create another FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLER? All the information concerning handling files using wizard I found at https://docs.djangoproject.com is about having to add a file_storage to the WizardView subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually uploading a file is a request, therefore you need to handle it with a view and then do whatever you want to do, including starting a celery task to handle file manipulation. The problem with that approach is the inability to serve a regular response to client if celery task returns something (but you can, for example, ping a special url from client side periodically or use socket.io to deliver the results).

One thing doesn't change - file upload, whether separate or within a regular form, is a request, and therefore you must first handle it with a view and only afterwards may pass received data to a task or handle it directly.

Further on, file upload handlers deal with receiving data from socket. I guess you could create one working in a celery task, or rather tasks, due to partial nature of data sent through sockets, but as far as I know your form data couldn't be accessed before the file is uploaded anyway (or in the better case, you can access all data but the file), so there is no point in sending it to celery, especially if you need to create a response involving some manipulation on the file.

Comment: So the very uploading process cannot be accessed and changed somehow (e.g. to send a task to Celery), is that right?

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadhandler.py - that's the way file upload works in django. I believe you could monkey-patch some internals to make it work differently, but it is definitely not a good idea. File upload should be left the way it is, whilst file manipulation (thumbnail generation etc) may be done using celery task.

Comment: But file_upload_handler's actually handle some data sent from MultiPartParser. Do you know what does MultiPartParser from https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/multipartparser.py work with? Is this class involved into uploading process?
In the method of receive_data_chunk() 'start' is also sent from MultiPartParser but not used.

Comment: yes, file upload handlers save the file which parser decodes (parser receives raw form data which may need to be decoded before writing); You could use file upload handler's `handle_raw_input` to override parser and prepare form data, but to use celery your broker would have to contain whole file, which means it has to be read and written in request processing anyway.

Comment: So a file is uploaded part by part while POST-request processing and these POST-data parts are fetched by MultiPartParser and sent to file_upload_handler further, is that right?

Comment: yes, that is how it works (there are usually proxies involved between application and client, in form of http server, ie. nginx, but that's the flow in django)